# How to show multiple array values in one row of php table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have return data like below json object,

```
{
    "user_token": "ad48c412-3866-4ac9-adf6-3328911ae46c",
    "order_info": {
        "order_id": "CGC12345678",
        "company_id": 32,
        "price": 1000.5,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "products": [
            { "type": "hr_claims", "name": "HR Claims", "is_fixed_price": true, "price": 500.5, "currency": "MYR" },
            { "type": "hr_leave", "name": "HR Leave", "is_fixed_price": true, "price": 500, "currency": "MYR" },
            { "type": "finance_advisory", "name": "FinanceAdvisory", "is_fixed_price": false, "currency": "MYR" }
        ],
        "total_invoices": 200,
        "total_staffs": 80
    }
}
```

i want to save this one object in php table one row but since products have 3 different array i cannot get all 3 [products][name] in to one record in php table.

Like below
products - HR Claims, HR Leave, Finance Advisory

Can someone help me?

This is i try! This one return last one!

```
<td>
    @php 
    $json = $order->data; 
    $json = json_decode($json, true); 
    $products = $json['order_info']['products']; 
    foreach ($products as $hitsIndex => $hitsValue) { 
        $data = $hitsValue['name']. '<br/>'; 
    } 
    @endphp 
    {{$data}}
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you done anything yourself yet? Can we see the code you have? "_in php table_" You mean a HTML table or a database table?

Comment: Yes html table. I add code in my question! @kerbholz

Comment: Could you provide something like a Paint image of the results you want to achieve ? I may be much clearer.

Comment: Do you have the option of saving the entire json string in your db table? On second thoughts I have no idea what kind of php table you're talking about

Comment: @MathieuBour i add json image to the question

Comment: @Dale according to json output in question, each object i need to same order id, company id, products in a single row. products can have multiple.

Comment: What about using a list (ul/li) for your products in order to display them into your table?

Comment: @MathieuBour No issue i just want display all the products in a single row for each order

Comment: `$data = $hitsValue['name']. '<br/>';` will overwrite `$data` on every iteration. And did you know that blade also has [loops](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop you overwrite `$data` on every iteration, that's why you only get the last entry. You need to concatenate your results to `$data`.

Change

```
foreach ($products as $hitsIndex => $hitsValue) {
    $data = $hitsValue['name']. '<br />';
}
```

to

```
$data = '';
foreach ($products as $hitsIndex => $hitsValue) {
    $data .= $hitsValue['name']. '<br />';
}
```